# Create user using Azure B2C in database after sign up

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to know is it possible to create user in database after user sign up in Azure B2C user flow.

What I mean is forward data from B2C sign up form to my backend API.

In Azure B2C, I see it is possible to get a token claim "newUser" with boolean value. Depending on this value I would send POST request to the API. Is it correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if "newUser" is set, call the API to write the user to the DB.